# Console fonts too small

Tags: windows, windows-8

Every time I start a new console program, its font size is too small to read by default, so I have to manually adjust it. But this gets quite annoying when you do this often.
I already tried adjusting cmd.exe's font size, but it worked only for cmd.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be affected by a bug that originates from Windows 7 RC that causes `cmd`'s default 8x12 font to go missing. When the default font is not available, `cmd` uses smallest raster font, 4x6:

[image: Screenshot of cmd window affected by the bug described]

The issue seems to affect Windows 7 RC and later when Slavic locale is set. It doesn't appear on first session since booting, only on subsequent ones, ie. when you log off and log in or after resuming from hibernation. This is especially troublesome on Windows 8.x as it uses Fast Boot (aka hybrid shutdown), so shutting down and booting up again doesn't count as first session. (Rebooting does, though, as it forces full shutdown.)

This issue has already been [discussed](https://serverfault.com/q/56093) on Server Fault.

Some solutions you may try:

- Disable Fast Boot. Shutting down and booting up will be slower, but `cmd` will work as expected on first session. This isn't really a good solution, as next sessions will still be affected.
- Try changing default font by using both the *Defaults* and *Properties* items from `cmd`'s title bar context menu:

  [image: cmd's title bar context menu with Defaults highlighted]

  Choose a vector font, for example 12pt Lucida Console. (this seems to work fine for me)
- Install [vector variant](http://www.yohng.com/software/terminalvector.html) of Terminal font. (I haven't tried this myself, [source](https://serverfault.com/a/263851))

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your display settings and check your results:

Go to search box > type Display > Settings > Display > now choose, Smaller (100%) or Medium (125%) or Larger (150%) and click Apply to take effect.

Also, you can check "Change only the text size" to adjust the font properties.

Hope this helps.